# Cannot login to my Drupal site

Tags: users, maintenance-mode

A while back I made a site for our [Operettic society in Holland](http://www.servus-almelo.nl), after a while I transferred the maintenance to another person who came just recently back at me with a problem.

The site is stuck in maintenance mode, and also the `/user/login` doesn't work, I also tried the `?q=user` possibility, but this also didn't work.

Also made the following query to the database:

```
UPDATE variable SET value = 's:1:"0";' WHERE name= 'site_offline';
DELETE FROM cache WHERE cid = 'variables';
```

Anyone some thoughts on this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you can login with ssh on the server you could use drush to unset the maintenance mode±

drush vset maintenance_mode 0

Comment: saddly enough my isp doesn't provide terminal access.

Comment: have a look at this page: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/100771/drupal-7-how-to-turn-off-maintenance-mode

Answer (score 0):

I got one solution [here](http://www.zyxware.com/articles/2570/how-to-log-in-programmatically-as-user-1-in-drupal-7). I faced this problem once and it worked for me.
I logged in to the application by admin programmatically using below code

```
 global $user;
    $user = user_load(1);
    drupal_session_regenerate();
    drupal_goto('user');
```

Make sure to delete the above code once the site is set back from maintenance mode. Otherwise this will give administration access to any user visiting the website.

Comment: I would recommend you to elaborate on your answer for the sake of completeness.

Comment: Very much so. I hope you don't intend to put that in the index.php or somewhere else that would run for any user that hits the page.